# How do I tell pipenv to use a library that is installed locally?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

Trying to use the neopixel library. It looks like it can't be installed with pipenv, as I get:

`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

When I try and install with:

`PIPENV_TIMEOUT=300 pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x.git#egg=neopixel\&subdirectory=python`

So I tried installing the neopixel library with these instructions here:

https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/software

and it works great. Personal projects and the demo both work with no issues.

However...I am now trying to integrate some code that uses the neopixel library with some other libraries that I install via pipenv. (As is best practice)

I have no reference to neopixel in my Pipfile (as stated above, it can't be installed via pipenv without that error)

But when I run my program with:
`pipenv run python foo.py`

It complains about the missing neopixel library.

How do I tell pipenv "Even though I am using a virtual env for most of my libraries, this **one** library **is not** found in the virtual env, but it **is** found globally on the OS" ?

Comment: what version of `pip` are you using? i've had some trouble with the most recent version of `pip` and `pipenv`

Comment: pip version is 18.1

Comment: pipenv version 2018.7.1

Comment: try downgrading your pip to version 18.0.0 - `pipenv run pip install pip==18.0.0` and then retry

Comment: No luck with 18.0.0, same error.

Answer (score 1):

This solution comes a bit late but I encountered exact same issue with 'numpy' package which couldn't be installed using pip on raspberrypi.

For anyone having same issue here is workaround: reinstall a new environment using following command:

`pipenv --three --site-packages`

From official pipenv [docs](https://pipenv-searchable.readthedocs.io/advanced.html#working-with-platform-provided-python-components):

> **Working with Platform-Provided Python Components**
>
> It’s reasonably common for platform specific Python bindings for operating system interfaces to only be available through the system package manager, and hence unavailable for installation into virtual environments with pip. In these cases, the virtual environment can be created with access to the system site-packages directory:
>
> $ pipenv --three --site-packages

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the latest version of pip — v18.1. 
So, if you are using pip 18.1 (`pip --version` to check the version) you need to downgrade to the previous version i.e v18 in order to get it working.

Run the following command to downgrade it:

`pipenv run pip install pip==18.0`

Reference to the GitHub issue: [pip 18.1 causes "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" #2924](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2924)